# ¿formatear fecha obtenia en jquery a otra fecha?

Tags: javascript, jquery

existe esta funcion en php
que permite formatear una fecha a la que quiero.
ejemplo:

```
$fechabd="29/02/2020 09:40:43 AM";
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s A', $fechabd);
echo $fecha->format('Y');
```

existe algun metodo o funcion similar que pueda usar en javascript jQUERY?

con la libreria moments doy el formato a la fecha:

```
    fecha1="29/02/2020 09:40:43 AM"
    
    var hr1=moment().format(fecha1,'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');

console.log("FECHA BD: ",hr1);
```

el resultado es este: `29/02/2020 09:40:43 AM8`

me esta arrojando un **8** al final. no sé si debo configurar algo antes de formatear las fechas, o porque me esta arrojando ese **8** al final

lo otro es como hago para mostrar solo el año?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas es pasar el formato en que `moment` va a recibir la fecha y el formato de salida, tanto en la fecha como en el año, algo así:

```js
fecha1="29/02/2020 09:40:43 AM"
    
var hr1 = moment(fecha1,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss a').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss a');

var hr2 = moment(fecha1,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss a').format('YYYY');

console.log("FECHA BD: ",hr1);
console.log("Año: ",hr2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nativamente no se encuentra algo específico que se encuentre en JQUERY para darle un formato especial o humano, podrías usar esta librería de jquery adicional que te ayuda con tu problema:

[Jquery Date Format][1]

Un pequeño ejemplo:

```
  jQuery(function() {
  var shortDateFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
  var longDateFormat  = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss';

  jQuery(".shortDateFormat").each(function (idx, elem) {
      if (jQuery(elem).is(":input")) {
          jQuery(elem).val(jQuery.format.date(jQuery(elem).val(), shortDateFormat));
      } else {
          jQuery(elem).text(jQuery.format.date(jQuery(elem).text(), shortDateFormat));
      }
  });
  jQuery(".longDateFormat").each(function (idx, elem) {
      if (jQuery(elem).is(":input")) {
          jQuery(elem).val(jQuery.format.date(jQuery(elem).val(), longDateFormat));
      } else {
          jQuery(elem).text(jQuery.format.date(jQuery(elem).text(), longDateFormat));
      }
  });
```

});

También tenemos interesantes librerías como moment.js que te permiten formatear de muchísimas formas una fecha

[Moment.js][2]

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // August 8th 2020, 4:18:00 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Saturday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Aug 8th 20
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2020 escaped 2020
moment().format();                         

  [1]: https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat
  [2]: https://momentjs.com/
```

Comment: var hr1=moment().format(years,'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss A'); ya formatee la fecha que recibo, pero de ahi solo quiero obtener el año o el dia,etc como seria?

Comment: tengo otro problema la fecha se me esta imprimiendo con un 8 al fina ejemplo 12/03/2020 10:45:11 AM8 ó 12/03/2020 10:45:11 PM8

Answer (score 0):

En Javascript existe la posibilidad de obtener ciertos datos con ciertos métodos.

```
var f = new Date();
var d = f.getDate(); // Obtienes el día (hoy: 10)
var y = f.getFullYear(); // Obtienes el año (2020)
var m = f.getMonth(); // Obtienes el mes.
var h = f.getHours(); // Obtienes las horas (ej: 11) sin minutos.
var min = f.getMinutes(); // Obtienes los minutos
var sec = f.getSeconds(); // Obtienes los segundos.
var mil = f.getMilliseconds(); // Obtienes los milisegundos
```

Espero que esta respuesta te sirva para crear una forma en conjunto a tu código.